# How to Cast or Stream all Playback Audio from Android device to a desktop Pc

Tags: android-pc

I have my Nokia 6 always next to my desk, and I'm using a desktop PC Windows 10 i7 64x
32gb ram and also running Voicemeeter, I use my desktop for everything, I can control all my devices from my desktop and I want to be able to listen any playback audio from my mobile device into my desktop audio system...

I don't need to cast the mic audio to my PC, just the playback audio
I'm not talking about streaming music either.

Anyone can help? Please thank you

Comment: AFAIK Windows 10 in it's newest release some days ago just got the feature to act as a Bluetooth A2DP sink (e.g pretend it is a Bluetooth headphone). Hence your phone would be able to send all audio signals to your desktop via Bluetooth. https://mspoweruser.com/a2dp-sink-feature-returns-to-windows-10/